# A question on conditional expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Consider the joint probability density function:

$$f(x_1,x_2)= 
\begin{cases}
2e^{-2x_1}, & \text{ for } 0 \le x_2 \le x_1 < \infty \\
0, & \text{ elsewhere} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Find the value of $E(X_1|X_2=x_2 )$ for $0 \le x_2 < \infty$

**My attempt:**

We know the formula for $$E(X|Y=y)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx=\frac{1}{f_Y(y)}x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx,$$ where $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal density function of the random variable $Y$.

Applying it here in this case, we have that $f_{X_2}(x_2)=\int_{x_2}^{\infty} 2e^{-2x_1}dx_1=e^{-2x_2}.$

So, we have that $$E(X|Y=y)=\frac{1}{e^{-2x_2}}\int_{x_2}^{\infty} x_12e^{-2x_1}dx_1= 2e^{2x_2} \bigg[x_1 \bigg(\frac{e^{-2x_1}}{-2} \bigg)-\bigg(\frac{e^{-2x_1}}{4}\bigg) \bigg]_{x_2}^{\infty}= 2e^{2x_2}\bigg[x_2 \bigg(\frac{e^{-2x_2}}{2} \bigg)+\bigg(\frac{e^{-2x_2}}{4}\bigg) \bigg] = x_2 + \frac{1}{2}.$$

So, $E(X_1|X_2=x_2 ) = x_2 + \frac{1}{2}.$

I have a problem here.

My answer is not matching with any of the options given.

I want to know where I have gone wrong.
Please point out my mistakes, if any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computations are correct as shown, but there is a problem with the joint density, since
$$\int_{x_2=0}^\infty \int_{x_1=x_2}^\infty 2e^{-2x_1} \, dx_1 \, dx_2 = \int_{x_2=0}^\infty e^{-2x_2} \, dx_2 = \frac{1}{2} \ne 1.$$
Check that the joint density is correctly specified.